# JOIN in combination with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, join

I want to find the earliest date in a table. How do I put this into a join statement:

```
SELECT date FROM table1 WHERE orderno = 222 ORDER BY date LIMIT 1
```

`Orderno 222` can have 1-* many rows in `table1` that's why I'm using `LIMIT 1`

I have table these tables:

Order
OrderLine
ProductionDate

Order can have 1-* ProductionDates so when i do my join of ProductionDate i want to find the earliest date.

So my guess of a sql statement would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Order
LEFT JOIN (
IN SELECT date FROM ProductionDate ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1)
```

but this doesn't work. And i would like to know what i should change to get it to work?

Comment: Can you specify your tables and which data you want to select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if MySQL supports a LIMIT In a derived table, but if it does, the syntax should be:

```
SELECT ord.*
FROM `Order` ord
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT date FROM ProductionDate ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1) t
       ON t.date = ord.date
```

Note that `order` is a reserved word, so you will need to quote it properly. Either using MySQL dreaded backticks (see above) or - if you configured your server to be standard's compliant - using double quotest like this: `"order"`

Comment: Yes, it does support `LIMIT` in subqueries like yours. But not in (IN/ALL/ANY) like this: `IN (SELECT ... LIMIT x)`

Comment: Just FYI running sub-queries can be very slow.

Comment: @DarkMantis: This is not a correlated subquery. I would expect the optimizer to schedule it to run once.

Comment: Lol, I like the way you say "expect" ;)

Comment: I know that the MySQL optimizer is not very smart, but if the requirements are like this, there is not much one can do about (or did I miss a different solution?)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `date` 
FROM `table1` 
INNER JOIN `table1`.`date` ON `table2`.`date`
ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Well no... i know how to do the select statement, but i want to put the select statement into a join statement...

Comment: What are you joining it to? There has to be a second table which you want to join it on